# PHP Laravel : How to logout from other device with same userId forcefully

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis

I'm building a laravel application where A user logged  in  other device and While logged out I want to force him to logged out from other device also. 
How do I implement in laravel.

Personally I have used Redis Server for that.But I don't know why It's not working. While running the program I have run `redis-server.exe` also.And I'm in Windows. And Here is my Controller where I have written the login for forcing the user from logged out from other device. If anyone find any solution please help me to find it out.Thanks In Advance.

Controller:

```
  public function postSignIn(Request $request)
  {       

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) ) {  
      $redis = \Redis::connection();   
      $userId = Auth::user()->id;
      $redis->sadd('users:sessions:' . $userId,Session::getId());      
      return redirect()->route('main');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}



public function getLogout()
{
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $userId =Auth::user()->id;
    $userSessions = $redis->smembers('user:sessions:' . $userId);
    $redis->sadd('users:sessions:'.$userId,Session::getId());
    $currentSession = Session::getId();
    foreach ($userSessions as $sessionId) {
      if ($currentSession == $sessionId) {
        continue; 
      }
      $redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);
      $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);
    }
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('main');
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the Redis storage class works like this `$redis->sadd($key, $value);`, you're only storing one session ID and each tome someone logs you're overwriting the previous one.

Comment: No because I have dd() the o/p and different session Id I have got.

Comment: Do you have the session driver changed in `config/session.php` to Redis or you're just using the Redis facade for the session IDs storage?

Comment: In config/session.php  I have changed it to  `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'redis'),` And the problem is Redis doesn't save any value in Session table I don't know why.

Comment: In you`.env` file do you have `SESSION_DRIVER=redis`?

Comment: `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`
`SESSION_DRIVER=redis`
`QUEUE_DRIVER=redis`

Comment: So you should be able to load the other sessions with the laravel session class with setId() and then use clear() to clear all the data from them. This should logout the users on other devices. https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Session/Store.html

Comment: can you explain me with some code please if possible?

Comment: check this out: https://codezen.io/how-to-manage-logged-in-devices-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

When you loop each user session load it by it's ID and clear all the data in it:

```
    foreach ($userSessions as $sessionId) {
        if ($currentSession == $sessionId) {
            continue;
        }
        $redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);
        $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);
        \Session::setId( $sessionId ); //ADD THIS
        \Session::clear(); //ADD THIS
    }
```

Comment: Same problem I'm facing ..logged out from one device but Couldn't logged out from others .. Thanks for helping though  ..

Comment: You should debug what is happening then. I would suggest writing down the session IDs of all devices you're testing on. You can get it like this `\Session::getId()`. Then check your redis to see if those session IDs are present for key 'user:sessions:' . $userId'.

Comment: There is no sessionId after I logged out as I have seen using dd();

Comment: There should be when you log in and it should be different on your devices. So compare these IDs to the data you have in your redis for this user.